# Issue corrupted when upgrading Ubuntu / Redmine

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, redmine

I have upgraded my system from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04. In the process, redmine has been upgraded. In 10.04 I was using the PPA ppa:ondrej/redmine, and in 12.04 I am using the Ubuntu stock version (1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1)

Most of the issues are still there, but I have problem with one specific issue: it is not listed, and accessing it directly (I had the link bookmarked) is throwing an error in the log:

```
Processing IssuesController#show (for AA.BB.CC.DD at 2012-10-19 11:19:24) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"issues", "id"=>"93"}

ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'WorkflowTransition'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Workflow.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.):
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:1671:in `instantiate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:665:in `collect!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:60:in `find'
  app/models/issue_status.rb:78:in `find_new_statuses_allowed_to'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
  app/models/issue.rb:471:in `new_statuses_allowed_to'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:122:in `show'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `perform_action_without_filters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/urlmap.rb:52:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'

Rendering /usr/share/redmine/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I have opened an issue related to this problem in the redmine forum, without success ([link](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/33951))

Comment: This question is off topic and belongs on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: It looks like, that not Redmine version was crashing. Its looks that ruby version was getting problem, had you checked the redmine ruby version and ubuntu ruby version?